# SQL inserting data into two different tables

Tags: java, sql, database, insert

I'm reading user data from a Java GUI and trying to record it into two different database tables with a single statement. I'm fond of the 'insert into' statement, I just dont know how to enter data into two different tables (which are linked with a foreign key in the one of them), using inner joins and stuff..

Please, any help is welcome.

So far I've had all columns I need in one table but after normalising the database to 3NF I'm not sure of how to insert into all of them..

Comment: Simple: use 2 insert statements, one for each table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle has some things called 'Triggers'. search something equivalent for your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two insert statements. In the first statement you have insert data in the primary table and in the second statement you have to insert on secondary table ( where first table reference id will be used)

If you do opposite there will be constraint violation error from database.